# Как работает функция ilLoadImage в с++?

Tags: c++, opengl

Есть функция из библиотеки которую хочу изучить.. она открывает фаил,

```
ILboolean ilLoadImage(const char *FileName);
```

Правильно ли я понял, что на аргумент этой функции надо присвоить значение?(Название файла)
То есть сперва я ее объявляю перед main?
А потом в уже вставляю в саму main, только уже в аргументе пишу название файла? ?

```
ilLoadImage("111.jpg");
```

Правильно же?

Comment: я думаю, Вам нужно чуточку больше деталей и чуточку переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: @Илья Дударь, если в библиотеке уже есть эта функция, то она уже и объявлена и определена. Зачем еще раз объявлять, тем более, что ваша объявленная функция может конфликтовать с уже существующей?...

Comment: Для начала с терминологией разобраться.

Comment: то есть я могу эту функцию не обьявлять? могу сразу в main писать ее? ну я еще немного не шарю в указателях... 
вообще правильно я сделал в своем примере? мене же надо аргументу присвоить название файла... как это сделать?

Comment: когда в "main" или в другой своей фукнции Вы пишите `ilLoadImage("111.jpg");`, то Вы уже вызываете функцию ilLoadImage и передаете имя файла в FileName (и функция внутри сможет им воспользоваться).

Comment: ну сделал как вы говорите! не стал в начале объявлять
и выдает 2 ошибки... 
E0167 аргумент типа "const char *" несовместим с параметром типа "const wchar_t *"


Ошибка C2664 "ILboolean ilLoadImage(const wchar_t *)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "const char [8]" в "const wchar_t *" Не может ли это ли говорить что библиотека установлена неправильно?

Comment: значит Вы неверно показали, как выглядит объявление функции. Но это легко пофиксить - `ilLoadImage(L"111.jpg");`

Comment: оо без ошибок!  спасибо! буду дальше изучать. значит wchar это другой тип или что? как называется эта тема?

Comment: wchar_t - это "широкий символ". да, оно выглядит очень похоже, но внутри там обычно 2 или 4 байта вместо 1.